# EDI using regex grouping and replacement string within positional boundaries

Tags: regex

I want to use regex to do a grouping with a search and replacement string technique for EDI purposes and can i force the replacment to be within a certain size constraint in my EDI output?

INPUT:

```
01234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
EINSTEIN            ALBERT              165
```

Regex Unnamed Grouping Search:

```
(.*{20})(.*{20})(.*{20})
```

Regex Grouping Replace:

```
First:\2Last:\1IQ:\3
```

Output:

```
01234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
First:ALB Last:EIN IQ:165
```

Comment: What kind of regex syntax is this? In the format I find familiar, is this essentially `(.{20})(.{20})(.{20})`? Anyway, if you want only the first three characters of each field and you know each field is 20 chars, could you capture the first three and not capture the next 17, like so? `(.{3}).{17}(.{3}).{17}(.{3}).{17}`

Comment: . is any character.  {20} is 20 times.

Comment: Also its grouping without names.  Heres with names {<myname>.*{20}}

Comment: Okay, and what about the `*`? I would interpret that as "0 or more", so `.*{20}` would be a nonsensical "0 or more characters 20 times" (invalid syntax). Out of curiosity, what regex engine or system is this? Do you have a link to its website/documentation?

Comment: True... I'm doing it from memory but maybe it does have a question mark in there like {?<myname>.{20}}. I think javascript has slightly diff syntax than the standard regex.

Comment: You're using JavaScript? JS has pretty standard syntax but lacks a few features. It doesn't have _named_ capturing groups (only numbered). And you'd use round parentheses for groups like I did, not curly braces. I've never seen curly braces used for groups, which is why I thought you were using some uncommon regex engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't seem to specify the tool you want to use (or I didn't get it) but this may give you some clues:

```
$ echo 'EINSTEIN            ALBERT              165' |\
> sed -r 's/(.{3}).{17}(.{3}).{17}(.*)/First:\2 Last:\1 IQ:\3/'
First:ALB Last:EIN IQ:165
```

Comment: Ohhh ... So in the i/p just don't include the stuff in a group you don't want to show in your result.

Comment: @RetroCoder, yep, that's the idea.